# User Authentication in Unit Testing Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5.1

I'm a bit confused about the unit testing in Laravel 5.1.

I want to test the updating of settings from a  user account. I'm using `phpunit` for testing.

This is my test case.

```
/** @test */
    public function it_updates_personal_details(){

        $this->withoutMiddleware();
        $this->visit('/account/settings')
            ->post('/account/settings', ["firstname"=>"RingoUpdated", 'lastname'=>"RingyUpdated", "username"=>"ringo", "bio"=>"My Personal Information", "facebook"=>"myFbUsername", "twitter"=>"myTwUsername", ])
            ->seeJson([
                "signup"=>true
            ]);
    }
```

But in my controller, I'm using `Auth::id()` to get the current logged in user's `id`. How can I mock this in `Laravel` 5.1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to make use of [Mockery in the Facade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#mocking-facades):

```
public function it_updates_personal_details(){
    Auth::shouldReceive('id')->andReturn(1);

    $this->withoutMiddleware();
    $this->visit('/account/settings')
        ->post('/account/settings', ["firstname"=>"RingoUpdated", 'lastname'=>"RingyUpdated", "username"=>"ringo", "bio"=>"My Personal Information", "facebook"=>"myFbUsername", "twitter"=>"myTwUsername", ])
        ->seeJson([
            "signup"=>true
        ]);
}
```

Comment: When running the test, I'm creating a test user. Is there any way to get the `id` of that user?

Comment: You could do something like this (it's ugly, but possible): `Auth::shouldReceive('id')->andReturn(DB::table('users')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first(['id'])->id);` - keep in mind that I haven't tested this, but that should get the ID of the last created user.

Comment: Actually... that may not work. It would get the last user before the new one you added.

Comment: Would there be any other way for doing this?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your architecture or the function that you're calling. You could use that method, but add 1 to the result, and pretend that that's correct (even less ideal). It really depends on how you're actually creating the user, etc.

Comment: I tried this: `$this->be(\App\User::where('username', 'ringo')->first());` and seems its working.

Answer (score 3):

That’s awesome, we can move to class TestCase for all test case and we can give a name, like this:

```
public function loginWithFakeUser()
{
      $user = new User([
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'yish'
      ]);

      $this->be($user);
}
```

When we need to authenticated user we can call loginWithFakeUser to pretend user.

Comment: Using this, I get a `Call to a member function guard()` on null at this line: `$this->app['auth']->guard($driver)->setUser($user);`. This is in Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

The ***[actingAs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing#sessions-and-authentication)*** helper method. Laravel 5.3

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

use App\User; // user model

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testApplication()
    {
        $user = User::find(1); // find specific user

        $this->actingAs($user)
             ->visit('/')
             ->see('Hello, '.$user->name);
    }
}
```

The actingAs helper method. provides a simple way to authenticate a given user as the current user.

You may also use a model factory to generate and authenticate a user:

```
        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();
        $this->actingAs($user)
         ->visit('/')
         ->see('Hello, '.$user->name);
```